# Avoiding <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xeafea58>

Tags: image, matplotlib, plot, graphics

I am trying to plot a series of functions on the same graphs. The code seems to run ok, but there is no picture coming coming out. just simply

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xeafea58>
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: I have tried switching backend .. `['TKAgg','GTKAgg','Qt4Agg','WXAgg']` but to no avail

Comment: I am running it using the Ipython console

Comment: What **is** the code? Be aware that this is the expected and desired behaviour, depending on your setup, so it cannot be "fixed".

Comment: I have just updated the function that plots the image. I image

Comment: did you switch the backend before or after you imported pyplot?

Comment: @PaulH, I have updated the question so that you can see how I'm switching the backend. My friend is able to run it on his machine and I cannot. I have no idea why

Comment: `import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")`

Comment: "Agg" is not an interactive backend, so no window will ever be displayed. Also pandas import pyplot, so you should import it *after* you select your backend.

Comment: @PaulH, it is only displaying on python console not on Ipython. but there the markery is not showing. none of the recommended back-ends have any effects whatsoever

Comment: Create a [mcve] (at most ten lines), run it, take a screenshot, and update your question with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the IPython console, the best way to make sure figures show up (without explicitly calling `plt.show()`) is to use `%matplotlib` mode. If matplotlib is installed correctly, it should automatically choose a suitable backend for your system.

For example:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: plt.plot([1, 2, 3])  # no plot shown!
Out[2]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x110eac898>]

In [3]: %matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: MacOSX

In [4]: plt.plot([1, 2, 3])  # plot shown now
Out[4]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x112174400>]
```

[image]

The `%matplotlib` magic command only needs to be entered once per session.

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp .. yayiiii it's really a magic commend. it has directly selected a backend for me and it works like magic lol  .. many thanks

Comment: I had to write `%matplotlib` before the import