# Maplotlib gives the list of array outputs before showing the scatter plot in Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a couple of plots before using Python 2.7 and everything is fine. Now I am trying to pick it up in Python 3 as I am trying to visualize some of the data output of the project I'm working on. So I tried to see if this works:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fake data:
a = np.random.normal(size=1000)
b = a*3 + np.random.normal(size=1000)

plt.hist2d(a, b, (50, 50), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar()
```

The result is quite confusing for me: it shows the plot but before the plot it also shows the list of value of a and b, as shown in the picture below:

[image: Part1]
[image: Part2]

All I need is a clean graph of the plot. So what have I done wrong here? Haven't used matplotlib for a long time so I guess I have made some big mistakes here.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: One hint here is to add a semicolon (;) to the end of the plot line. This will suppress the text output in the jupyter notebook.

Comment: Damn, I was trying to add ; to each plt. line. And apparently it only works if I added in another line : plt.show(). This is great. Thanks a lot. Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert but what happens is that you are getting as results the variables that make your plot. I have run it into [Spyder](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) and on the right (variables section) I also get your results. What you need to do however, is to write explicitly "show the plot":

```
....
plt.colorbar
plt.show()
```

This will plot automatically your plot in a new window without showing all the arrays. Here some explanation [Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504109/avoiding-matplotlib-figure-figure-at-0xeafea58).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using the Jupyter Notebook. I add the "plt.show()" at the end but the output is still the same.

Comment: What if you try `%%capture` as mentioned here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692950/how-do-you-suppress-output-in-ipython-notebook) or here  [link](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/)

Comment: Somehow this makes no difference, but the semicolon method mentioned in a comment in your first link works. I just put the ; at the end of "plt.show()" and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, so that's a go.